# Regex doesn't Work , Regex between 2 String

Tags: regex, vb.net

Please help me. I have a strange error with Regex:

```
    Const AGC = "s$(.*)s"
    Dim ORIGINAL As String = "s$1s"
    Dim lel As Regex = New Regex(AGC)
    Dim lol As Match = lel.Match(ORIGINAL)
    MsgBox(lol.Success)
    MsgBox(lol.Groups(0).Value)
```

The following code doesn't work , i don't know why.

Comment: Welcome! What do you want to achieve? You want to get the number after $ and before s or? Please give us more details and implement them in your question.

Answer (score 2):

This is because the `$` is a special character. You need to escape it in your Regex:

```
Const AGC = "s\$(.*)s"
```

The rest of the code should work fine:

```
Const AGC = "s\$(.*)s"
Dim ORIGINAL As String = "s$1s"
Dim lel As Regex = New Regex(AGC)
Dim lol As Match = lel.Match(ORIGINAL)
MsgBox(lol.Success)
MsgBox(lol.Groups(0).Value)
```

See it in action [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DjHjlF).

<sub>I posted a C# version of this answer in the previous revision accidentally!</sub>

Answer (score 1):

`$` is a special regex character showing end-of-line. You'll have to use `\$` to actually specify the dollar character in the regex expression. Your new expression will be `"s\$(.*)s"`. Use sites such as [Regex Storm .Net tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester) to test your regexes when you're new to them. Link to this regex and its test:

[http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=s%5c%24(.*)s&i=s%241s](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=s%5C%24(.*)s&i=s%241s)